# $_FILES and $_POST data empty when uploading certain files

Tags: php, html, multipartform-data

I've noticed that depending on the video I'm uploading that sometimes the entire `$_POST` and `$_FILES` array will be empty. This is an odd occurrence but I have found it in a few videos. For the sake of testing the videos I was using are all of `video/mp4` file type.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);
?>
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="attachment">
    <input type="text" name="other">
    <button type="submit" class="save" value="Save Changes">Upload that file!</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

The output of a good video is

```
Array
(
    [other] => testing string
)
Array
(
    [attachment] => Array
        (
            [name] => Shasta.mp4
            [type] => video/mp4
            [tmp_name] => /private/var/tmp/phpAoDLKi
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 4688949
        )

)
```

While a bad request displays the following

```
Array
(
)
Array
(
)
```

I've modified my php.ini to allow file uploads to the size of 50mb, the files I'm testing with are 4.7mb and 10.2mb. I'm completely stumped on what the cause is, the video file names are `Shasta.mp4` (good file) and `Bulova_Watches.mp4` (bad file).

If need be I can upload the files to a site for others to test.

Comment: Are you sure the bad file is encoded properly and is not corrupt?

Comment: Have you looked at your `max_post_vars`/`max_input_vars` variables?

Comment: @Darren nothing is currently set, I'll add them and have a play to see if there is any change in the result. Would changing the max vars really have an effect on it when I'm only using 2 inputs.

Comment: @Bankzilla It might not affect anything but I ran into something similar and changing the upload size and these two variables managed to fix it!

Comment: @KaiQing The videos play correctly. Although using Firefox developer edition, when i try play both files they say they're corrupt. In chrome it plays the audio but no video for both.

Comment: @Darren you might be onto something, I believe settings the `max_input_vars` to 3000, I'm now getting the error `POST Content-Length of 10237675 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608 bytes in Unknown`

Comment: @Bankzilla Thats the way I was heading with the errors, I had to set it to something major if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Darren I set it to 20000 and the error is gone but the issue is still the same, empty arrays :(

Comment: @Bankzilla Have you tried other large files to see if the current ones aren't corrupt? Also, try setting your timeout limit in your php.ini file to something high! That could be the other issue causer!

Comment: @Darren had an issue with another larger file, so will test other sized files ranging from 8mb to 20mb. Maybe the file upload limits is having some affect to files large than 5mb even though I've set it higher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76114/discussion-between-bankzilla-and-darren).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to the fact that `post_max_size` is set to `8M` as default in your `php.ini`.
As your file is `10.4MB` you run into the following error:

> POST Content-Length of 10237675 bytes exceeds the limit of 8388608
>   bytes in Unknown

Because you've reached that limit.
The trick to fixing this is to simply up that limit by changing the value. You could simply change it directly in your php.ini file to whatever you desire, i.e. 20M.

Or you could set it via your `.htaccess` file with:

```
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
```

<sup>*Note: I've also added the required `upload_max_filesize` that you will require for the bigger files :)*</sup>