# hook save_post is not called with hook post_edit_form_tag

Tags: wordpress

I'm developping a plugin to create custom post type.
This custom post type has custom attachment fields (meta box).
In tese custom attachment fields, there is an upload field.

I have to use hook post_edit_form_tag to add enctype to the form.

```
add_action('post_edit_form_tag',  'updateEditForm');
function updateEditForm() {

    printf(' enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data" ');
}
```

But with this hook, the system no longer goes into the function savePost :

```
add_action('save_post', 'savePost', 10, 2 );
// or add_action('save_post_vwvideo', 'savePost', 10, 2 );
function savePost($post_id, $post)
{
    print_r($_FILES);
```

die('here');
    }

If I desactivate the hook post_edit_form_tag, the system call savePost but the $_FILES is empty...

I create the custom post (vmvideo) with register_post_type and add meta box with register_meta_box_cb.

is there is a code to force the call of savePost ?

thanks

Phil

Comment: i cannot find any documentation for a `save_post_$type` hook, only for `save_post` without type, did your action hook actually work before?

Comment: line 3398 in wp-includes/post.php I see this
do_action( "save_post_{$post->post_type}", $post_ID, $post, $update );

Comment: yes, the answer to my question is in the question. You can still trigger an action manually with `do_action( 'action_hook_name', $param );`, but be careful it's not triggered twice

Comment: where can i call do_action('save_post'...) ?

Comment: well that's just a workaround, the best would be to understand why it's not called. But if your first hook prevents the second, trigger the second from the first (tricky part is you have to retreive the post to pass it)

Comment: Sorry !!! it's not wordpress, it's my php config.
I found the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29836496/files-and-post-data-empty-when-uploading-certain-files
I change php config post_max_size and upload_max_filesize and it's ok

Comment: yeah it's always useful to add a `echo` or `var_dump` test to functions you have a doubt, just to be sure it is actually executed ;)